# breeze-sequelize soft delete implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, breeze, sequelize.js

Im currently digging into `breeze-sequelize` and i am questioning myself how i should implement a `soft delete`. I already searched a bit, though could not find anything.

My stack contains angularjs breezejs nodejs & breeze-sequelize.

Is there any configuration i can implement to automatically do a soft delete?

If not - what would be the best approach to implement it? Should i do it on the server or on the client? Overwrite the save changes?

I am happy about any idea you got for me!